# .htaccess rewrite to default language folder?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have my site broken down into several folders by language:

```
/
  /en/
    index.php
    about-us.php
    faq.php
    ...

  /fr/
    index.php
    about-us.php
    faq.php
    ...

  ...
  etc.
```

I'd like to have a rewrite rule that automatically rewrites to the `en` folder if somebody tried to enter `mydomain.com/about-us.php`.

FYI, I also already have a rewrite rule in place that removes the extension, so really I want to make sure that `mydomain.com/about-us` rewrites to `mydomain.com/en/about-us`.  Here's my existing rewrite rule that does this:

```
# allows for extension-agnostic urls 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

That make sense? Anyone help me out here?

EDIT:

@Gumbo -

Here's what my `.htaccess` file looks like (this is all that's in it):

```
RewriteEngine On

# defaults to the english site
RewriteRule !^[a-z]{2}/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# allows for extension-agnostic urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This file is in the root of my website (not in a language folder). I've reloaded my webserver, just to be on the safe side, and I still get this error message when I try to go to `mydomain.com/about-us`:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /about-us was not found on this server.
```

... where `mydomain.com/en/about-us` works just fine.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directives belong to the `RewriteRule` you previously had and not to the new one. So you need to arrange the directives as `RewriteRule … RewriteCond … RewriteCond … RewriteRule` where the first `RewriteRule` is my rule and the rest is your original rule.

Comment: Okay, I changed it, but I'm getting the same error. It seemed to have made no difference.

Comment: (edited entry above to reflect the new rule order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this rule before your rule:

```
RewriteRule !^(fr|en)/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or more general:

```
RewriteRule !^[a-z]{2}/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I prefer the second but I guess it depends on the number of languages. +1

Comment: Neither seems to be working for me. I put your rule--verbatim--after my two rewrite conditions and before my existing rewrite rule, but no joy (file not found). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @neezer: Where do you want to use that rule?

Comment: @Gumbo: Well, I'd like to use it where ever it will work. I have it now in the .htaccess file in my site's root.

Comment: @neezer: Well, it should work for your .htaccess file in the document root.