# RewriteRule multilanguage site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have site with many languages
extra  languages are in  subdomains on my server like de.mydomain.com, fr.mydomain.com.
in these de,fr subdirectory i've placed only htaccess file with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.de\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.mydomain.com/$1?lan=2%1" [L]
```

And it works but not how I want. it simply redirects from de.mydomain.com to mydomain.com, url in the browser is changing and I would like the url to stay like: de.mydomain.com but the content to be taken from mydomain.com?lan=2.(i use lan variable to change lang)

what do I do wrong here?
maybe my general aproach to this problem is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :**

You need to point de subdomain to the root directory instead, and then adding these lines to the root htaccess file :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?de\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lan=2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I have Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: Ok, then you will need to point the de subdomain to the root directory instead of the "de" folder, and after that adding a specific rule to the root htaccess, can you change where de is poiting ?

Comment: it works onlt i had to remove one slash from your code: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lan=2 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

**Put this rule before your rule:**

```
RewriteRule !^(fr|en)/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

[.htaccess rewrite to default language folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689283/htaccess-rewrite-to-default-language-folder)

Comment: thanks but it seems to be not what I want to do. and it also doesn't work for me