# What is wrong with this simple rewrite rule that doesnt redirect?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Good day to everyone,

I'm struggling trying to understand what is wrong with this simple rule that doesn't work.
I have a website that has URLs like that: site.com/support, I now want to redirect all the URLs site.com to site.com/en, site.com/support/ to site.com/en/support/, ....

After many tries and search, I came up with the 2 following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(?![a-z]{2}/)(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L] # redirect to default language
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

each of these rules work perfectly separately, but result in a too many redirects when combined (?lang=en&lang=en&lang=en...)

any one could tell me pls what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did  you try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689294

Comment: hi, is there an other solution than the one in the referred link coz it's not working with my second rule and really can't figure out what's wrong! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that both rules are modifying `REQUEST_URI` and causing each other to execute repeatedly until browser detects a redirect loop and stops redirecting with an error.

You can fix it by using:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to default language
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(?![a-z]{2}/)(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200` condition will prevent redirect loop as Apache will set `REDIRECT_STATUS` env variable to `200` after first successful execution of 1st rule.

Comment: OMG, thousand thanks @anubhava, don't know how to thank you :) it's working perfectly. Thank you, thank you, thank you :))))) I just can't believe it's working. You're my saver :))

Comment: Hi again, I have a bad news, the redirection causes a server crash after around 5min. I had to roll back to the previous version :( any idea what that may be?

Comment: I myself don't understand how it could work for few minutes then returns an error. sorry, I was meaning a Site crash not Serve! here is the returned error: Failed connect to www.site.com:443; Connection refused

Comment: port 443 just because our website runs only on SSL... :) OK thanks a lot, i'll let you know when I have more details, our server admin will have a look at this soon. meanwhile, do you by any chance have in mind another rewrite rules? maybe I can try it and with some luck it may work :)

Comment: Hey @anubhava, how are you? I finally got it working, it was due to the load balancer that was not returning a 200 response, and that's why it wasn't working properly... so thank you so much once again for your time and help. cheers :)

Comment: Hi again anubhava, one last thing that i can't figure out. I have same cases where the redirection should be different. We have an AMP version if the site, so site.com/amp/my-page/, should be redirected to site.com/amp/en/my-page/. I have the following rule for the AMP: `RewriteRule ^amp/(.*)$ /$1?amp=1 [QSA,L]` Thanks again :)

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question as that problem is not trivial and is different from this question.

Comment: ah, don't you think it's linked to the original question about the language redirections??

Comment: I have been restrained by SO admin against long discussions in comments section. That's why I suggested a new question with all the details. You can link this question and clarify why this is not working for `/amp` URI

Comment: Ah OK, sorry about that :S OK, i'll do some research and if i don't succeed, then i'll create a new question :) cheers

Comment: impossible to get it work, so i crated a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892995/redirect-to-default-language-except-form-amp-urls