# Redirect to default language except for /amp/ URLs

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm struggling to solve a redirection but without any success.

I changed the URLs of my site forcing a default language, before it was site.com/help/ and now it's `site.com/en/help/`. Thanks to help from Stack Overflow I made the redirection, but then I faced a new problem with the AMP pages: `site.com/amp/help/` are now redirected to `site.com/en/amp/help/` while they are supposed to be `site.com/amp/en/help/`.

Again, thanks to help on this site, I changed the structure of URLs to `site.com/en/help/amp/` (amp always at the end). To achieve this, I had to delete the .php extension I had in some pages and also decided to remove the trailing slash.

I'm now facing two new issues: the 301 redirection to a non .php page and URLs with trailing slashes to a non trailing slash don't work. Below is my htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine on

# amp
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?amp/(.+?)/?$ /$1$2/amp [R=301,NC,L]

## redirect to default language (fr)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/inc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ajax/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/img/
RewriteRule ^(?![a-z]{2}(?:[/-]|$))(.*)$ /fr/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]

## add trailing slash in front of directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?/(.+)$ /$1/ [L]

# remove .php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !global.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ajax/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !results.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,NC,NE,L]

## amp pages
RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp$ /$1?amp=1 [NC,QSA,L]

## folders of languages
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

## hide .php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !global.js
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: in root directory. And I actually don't have any amp directory

Comment: we just decided to make /amp the root for AMP pages and all languages, how would you do it you?

Comment: OK, I thought about doing it differently now, what do you think about site.com/en/help/amp/ (amp/) always at the end

Comment: I4m just trying to use a simple and single convention for that :) So i'll go for `site.com/en/help/amp/` that i think is the best :)

Comment: OK, i'll do that and will let you know :) thanjs again for your advices :)

Comment: Hi anubhava, hope you had a great weekedn :) I managed to change everything and seems to be working perfectly. However i do have one tiny little problem that i can't figure out. Since I moved /amp at the end of the URL, i had to change some URLs that ends with .php for example site.com/help/contact.php, then i sent a rule to redirect all URLs that end with .php to a page without .php (site.com/help/contact/): `RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]` but the rule doesn't work, do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

# changed amp URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?amp/(.+?)/?$ /$1$2/amp/ [R=301,NC,L]

## redirect to default language (en)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/img/
RewriteRule ^(?![a-z]{2}(?:[/-]|$))(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]

## add trailing slash in front of directories after lang rewrite
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?/(.+[^/])$ /$0/ [L]

# remove .php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,NE,L]

## amp pages
RewriteRule ^(.+/)amp/?$ /$1?amp=1 [NC,QSA,L]

## folders of languages
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

## hide .php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !global.js
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

**Explanation** of this trailing slash rule:

```
## add trailing slash in front of directories after lang rewrite
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?/(.+[^/])$ /$0/ [L]
```

Take an example URI: `/fr/cart`.

In a later rule we remove `lang` component from URL and pass it as `lang=<fr|en>` query parameter. Part after `lang` parameter e.g. `/cart` doesn't have a trailing slash and if it is a real directory then `/cart?lang=fr` will be redirected to `/cart/?lang=fr` by Apache's `mod_dir` module and your internal URL will be exposed in browser.

So in this current rule we capture part after `lang` component and check if we don't have a trailing slash and it is a directory then this rule internally rewrites to `/fr/cart/` with a trailing slash. Later rule then rewrites it to `/cart/?lang=fr` and `mod_dir` doesn't redirect anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I have tried it but it doesn't work well: when i go to site.com/es, it redirects to .com/en/es :(

Comment: now there is a new problem: if i type /en/cart/, it results on a too many time redirections: /en/cart?lang=en&lang=en&lang=en... of course i cleared browser cache for tests

Comment: OK, i noticed that if the folder "cart" exists which is my case, the too many redirects occurs, but if I type `/cartt`, it redirects me well to `/en/cartt`

Comment: it's working now but broke other rules :( for example `/amp/fr/cart` redirects to `/fr/amp/fr/cart` and `/fr/amp/cart` while they both must redirect to `/fr/cart/amp`

Comment: Hi anibhava, sorry to bother you again. I went on prod with the rules you gave me but some issues are happening and can't roll back :( is there please a way to PM you or chat with you to solve the problem? it's really urgent! thanks

Comment: OK, I have detected the error, it actually doesn't get the `lang` parameter when going to `site.com/fr/cart` where `cart` is a real folder!

Comment: OMG, you're really a true saver, thank you thank you thank you sooooo much :) would you please explain me what is `RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?/(.+[^/])$ /$0/ [L]` for? i didn't get it!

Comment: Have added explanation in my answer. At the same time I suggest reading some good resource on `mod_rewrite` to understand it completely. I found https://www.askapache.com/ a pretty good resource.

Comment: sorry, just forgot to change it :) and thanks for the explanations in your edited message. it's more clear to me now :) have a lovely day and once again, thanks a lot for all

Comment: hi @anubhava, how are you? please one very little question if you don't mind. following our SEO agency, they recommended us to switch to .fr, .be instead of .com/fr and .com/be. since I now removed the language folder, removing the trailing slash does't really work well. site.com/test adds the trailing slash because the folder "test" exists and is a folder. I tried `DirectorySlash Off` but it returns a forbidden 403 error. please any idea how to solve this? Thanks a lot

Comment: thank you, it's done :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635598/remove-trailing-slash-from-real-directories

Comment: hi @anubhava, hope you're doing well and sorry to bother you, you've always been my savior, i posted a question but no one has been able to give me a solution that works, would you please have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414527/redirect-domain-to-default-language-nginx ? thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, i think you have replied but i don't see it anymore, was there a something going on or am i missing something?

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted later because you're problem was unclear to me

Comment: Ah, but what was unclear? hope you can help, you're really my last chance :D

Comment: I usually don't answer nginx Anders but in particular I don't understand how rules can cause high CPU

Comment: OK, no problem. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

@anubhava's solution works perfectly well except for one little case: `/fr/amp/page.php` redirects to `/fr/page.php/amp`, I had to make some changed to the code and managed to make it work. Below is the updated code with small changes I made:

1- removed some slashes at the end of some rules as I don't need them any more

2- removed this rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp/$ [NC]`

3- to fix the .php problem, I replaced `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,NE,L]` by `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,NC,NE,L]`.

```
RewriteEngine on

## changed amp URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?amp/(.+?)/?$ /$1$2/amp [R=301,NC,L]

## redirect to default language (en)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/img/
RewriteRule ^(?![a-z]{2}(?:[/-]|$))(.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]

## add trailing slash in front of directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?/(.+)$ /$1/ [L]

# remove .php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,NC,NE,L]

## amp pages
RewriteRule ^(.+/)amp$ /$1?amp=1 [NC,QSA,L]

## folders of languages
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

## hide .php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !global.js
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for compiling a working example based on someone else's answer, that may well be helpful for another reader. However, some of the bullet-points here were in fact supplementary questions, and they do not belong in answers. It seems that you have had a comment conversation with your helper, and asked a new question - which is the correct thing to do.