# Remove trailing slash from real directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

how are you? please one very little question if you don't mind.

after the previous episode of redirecting and rewriting rules in this thread: [redirect to default language except for /amp/ Urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892995/redirect-to-default-language-except-for-amp-urls), our SEO agency recommended us to change the URLs site.com/fr, site.com/be to site.fr and site.be

I already set the 301 redirections for old URLs as follow:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I know this can be achieved in one rule but didn't manage to make it work :/

since I now removed the language folder, removing the trailing slash does't really work well. site.com/test adds the slash because the folder "test" exists and is a real folder. I tried DirectorySlash Off but it returns a forbidden 403 error.
please any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: i've updated my post, hope it's more cleat

Comment: i wont use language/ localization folders anymore, site.com/fr/contact becomes site.fr/contact & site.com/uk/contact becomes site.co.uk/contact

Comment: i don't have access to the VHosts :( there is no problem with site.com/test/, it's just that all the website doesn't have trailing slashes, so i want to keep the same thing...

Comment: You must allow trailing slash after real directories for security reasons otherwise disable directory listing using `Options -Indexes`. With trailing slash not being a problem I think question needs to be edited as it is unclear what is the core problem.

Comment: I currently use `Options All -Indexes` in my htaccess, I changed it to `Options -Indexes` but the slash is still appearing at the end... is renaming the real folders then make a rewrite rule a good solution to prevent the trailing slash?

Comment: ah! you said "You must allow trailing slash after real directories for security reasons otherwise disable directory listing using Options -Indexes", i understood that this was the solution! so what do you recommend me knowing that i have real folders and that i need to remove the trailing slash?

Comment: haha, I know but it doesn't solve my problem :/ i'll need to remove the trailing slashes from real directories. we previously had the trailing slashes, I removed them from all the website, i can't have them back now for some folders :(

Comment: I ended up using this solution: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102947/removing-slash-from-directory-url what do you think about it?

Comment: Yes that's a good answer. If you note I already had a rule below this comment `## add trailing slash in front of directories after lang rewrite` to add a trailing slash in front of directories with matching pattern.

Comment: OK thanks :) please, the 2 rules I mentioned in my initial post, how would you write them within 1 rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments:

Combining those 2 shown rules into one:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: hey, please again one other 2 rules that i can't write into 1 single rule: 

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp$ /$1?amp=1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)amp$ /$1?amp=1 [NC,QSA,L]`

the first rule doesn't apply for the home page (site.fr/amp) that's why i had to add the second one. how can i group them into one rule pls? thanks

Comment: May be `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?amp/?$ $1?amp=1 [NC,QSA,L]`

Comment: That's what your 2 rules were doing. Also let me request again that I don't like to solve problems over comments. Even though I tried to help but if it doesn't work then please open a new question.