# Redirect domain to default language NGINX

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

Been struggling for so long to 301 redirect `site.com` to `site.com/en` and `site.com/my-page` to `site.com/en/my-page`

I manage to make the first redirect work, but not the second! also is it possible to use only one rule for both? So what is wrong with my second rule?

```
rewrite "^/(?![a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})$" /en redirect;
rewrite "^/(?![a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})/(.*)$" /en/$2 redirect;
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have 2 capture groups in the the second regexp, only one. The first pair of parenthesis there is a negative lookahead, which doesn't create a capture group. That's why you cannot use $2 in redirect.

**Updated**

This redirect should replace both your rules:

```
rewrite "^((?!/([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})(/|$)).*)$" /en$1 last;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. I just tried your code but it doesn't work, the page doesnt load and the fans of my laptop start spinning... and when i click on the button "stop", it appends an 'en' at the end (site.com/en/en)

Comment: still the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can approach it from the other angle, by defining relevant locations, e.g.:

```
location / {
    return 301 /en$request_uri;
}

location = /my-page {
    return 301 /en/my-page;
}

location /en/ {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Danila and thanks for your answer. `/my-page` can be any other URL, is it possible to make it dynamic?

Comment: when i go to `site.com`, it redirects to `site.com/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/` :(

Comment: It may mean that the `/en/` location wasn't added, have you added it? It is OK for it to be empty like `location /en/ { }`. The idea is that NGINX selects one location anyway.

Comment: I added it but the page doesnt reload and seems like it consumes so much CPU and my fans start spinning :(
I didnt know nginx was more complicated, this is something i can easily do with apache in .htaccess!!